# Separable and finitely generated projective but not Frobenius?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-algebra, topological-quantum-field-theory, frobenius-algebras

Let R be a commutative ring, and $A$ an $R$-algebra (possibly non-commutative). Then $A$ is separable if it is finitely generated (f.g.) projective as an $(A \otimes_R A^{\mathrm{op}})$-algebra. Suppose further that $A$ is f. g. projective as an $R$-module. Does this imply that $A$ is a (symmetric) Frobenius algebra?

There are lots of equivalent definitions of a Frobenius algebra. One (assuming $A$ is a f.g. projective R-module) is that there exists an $R$-linear map $\mathrm{tr}: A\to R$, such that $b(x,y) := \mathrm{tr}(ab)$ is a non-degenerate.

I know that the answer is yes when $R$ is a field. What about other rings?

I am not an expert on algebras, but this question is related to understanding obstructions for extended TQFTs, and so I am very interested in knowing anything I can about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theorem 4.2 of [On separable algebras over a commutative ring](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/osaka-journal-of-mathematics/volume-4/issue-2/On-separable-algebras-over-a-commutative-ring/ojm/1200691953.full) says that the answer is always yes.

Comment: Okay great! I see that Thm 4.2 also has the assumption that A is a faithful R-module. Can that be removed? or is it automatic?

Comment: It is not automatic but I imagine will be true in any case that you might be interested in. Otherwise, you could replace R by a suitable quotient ring.